# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host : 192.168.90.157 , port: 25

Tags: java

I am getting issue while sending email.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 192.168.90.157, port: 25;
      nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1706)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
        at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:29)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:284)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:227)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1672)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: so either there is no service at `192.168.90.157, port: 25;` or access is denied due to firewall or other reasons.

Comment: Show us some code you tried

Comment: @Asfab How would that help in this case?

Comment: @Henry I thought it may be issue with session property, I got same Exception while working with java mail.